# Suggest right Validation Rule?

Tags: apex, trigger, administration, validation-rule

Account field and integration__c fields combination of record is have already in case object don't allows duplication 
   if sftype__C checkbox is true otherwise allows if sftype__c is false allows for duplication.

1. I have created a unique text  field on case object.
2. I have created a workflow rule with field update action
3. In formula i have passed

formula:

```
  Account.Name & IntegrationTo__c  & IF(SfType__c, 'TRUE', 'FALSE')
```

and activate the workflow rule

but the case object allows the duplicate values 
  anyone suggest right formula to achieve the above requirement.

This is my trigger but this is also allows duplicates please check it once

```
trigger AvoidDuplicateInsertions on Case(before insert,before update){

         Set<string> accountname= new Set<string>();
         Set<string> integrationto= new Set<string>();


         for(Case cas: Trigger.new){

           accountname.add(cas.Account.Name);
           integrationto.add(cas.IntegrationTo__c);

         }

       List<Case> duplicatecaseList = [Select id,Case.Account.Name,IntegrationTo__c,SFType__c From Case where Case.Account.Name= :accountname AND IntegrationTo__c =:integrationto];

       Set<string > duplicatecaseIds = new Set<string >();

       for(Case dup: duplicatecaseList ){

          duplicatecaseIds .add(dup.Account.Name);
          duplicatecaseIds .add(dup.IntegrationTo__c);

       }

       for(Case s : Trigger.new){

            if(s.Account.Name!=null && s.IntegrationTo__c!=null){


               if(duplicatecaseIds.contains(s.Account.Name) && duplicatecaseIds.contains(s.IntegrationTo__c)){

                  if(s.SFType__c = true){

                      s.addError('Record already exist with same Service');
                  }

                }

            }
       }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: @thanks for quick replying yes. i searched in google for some reference i found one like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use case will not be serve like that way, if you are making a unique field and updating the value based on checkbox indicator.

As because think about a scenario, first time checkbox is false and you are making an update, it will create a value like `Account.Name & IntegrationTo__c & 'FALSE'` and next time also based on same checkbox as false condition it will try to create same `Account.Name & IntegrationTo__c & 'FALSE'` and you will receive error due of uniqueness. which you don't want.

I will suggest that, remove uniqueness of the field and update like this from workflow:

`Account.Name & IntegrationTo__c`

Create a before insert trigger which will check the uniqueness of the record to be inserted based on checkbox condition.

Validation rule will not work here because validation rule is executed first followed by workflow rule.

Comment: I have updated my question with trigger but it also allows duplicates please check it once

Comment: you may refactor the code, also use if (s.SFType__c) instead of if(s.SFType__c = true), otherwise it will always assigned to true

Comment: i changed as you said but it the trigger isn't working properly

Comment: from yesterday i'm fighting with this Santanu anyway thanks.